# Can't keep elements from overlapping when using GSAPs stagger method

Tags: javascript, animation, gsap

So I am trying to stagger some letters using TweenMax.staggerTo.

Here is the JS:

```
TweenMax.staggerTo(letter, 2, {bottom:0, opacity: 1, delay: 2}, 1);
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="middle">
  <p class="letter">p</p>
  <p class="letter">p</p>
  <p class="letter">p</p>
  <p class="letter">p</p>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.letter {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.middle {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
 }
```

One of the official tutorials I watched explains that the position on the element being animated needs to have a position property of either absolute or fixed.

I am confused though, how I can animate these objects without have them all overlapping each other. 
This is an example of what I am going for: [GSAP Staggered Animated Elements](https://youtu.be/tMP1PCErrmE?t=609)

Thanks!

Comment: possible for you to create a fiddle demo?

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same problem and, please consider that I'm a beginner too, the staggerTo method is not appropriate for this example.

Let's look at the official definition of the staggerTo method by GreenSock :

```
Tweens an array of targets to a common set of destination values, but 
staggers their start times by a specified amount of time, creating an    
evenly-spaced sequence with a surprisingly small amount of code.
```

So, If I understand, the most important thing to keep in mind is that it tweens an array of targets to a **common set of destination values**. So that is why your letters are overlapping with eachother, that have the same destinations values, which is how the staggerTo method is used basically.

What I tried to do in order to solve this problem is that, since all of my Elements are in an array, I used the forEach() Method in javascript and increments the index each loop.

Here is the codepen modified, please, feel free to ask again if you don't undestand : [CodePen Solution](http://codepen.io/Maieon/pen/zBjNNV)

Basically what I just did is like doing a simple timeline and adding a to method for each letter.

Hope it helps !

Happy Tweening

Answer (score -1):

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/beEXQM) of what I am talking about

```
<div class="middle">
 <p class="letter">h</p>
 <p class="letter">e</p>
 <p class="letter">l</p>
 <p class="letter">p</p>
</div>

.letter {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.middle {
 text-align: center;
 height: 100vh;
 margin: auto;
 position: relative;
}

var letter = document.getElementsByClassName("letter");
TweenMax.staggerTo(letter, 2, {bottom:0, opacity: 1}, 1);
```

Comment: Your codepen link should be placed in your above question.. not posted as an answer!